# Can't use inline constraints in CREATE TABLE

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have the following as a CREATE TABLE in Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE cs2_users (
    empnum     varchar2(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    toolsId    varchar2(20) 
        CONSTRAINT nn_cs2_users_toolsId NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_cs2_users_users FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users.userid,
    admin      number(1,0) DEFAULT 0
        CONSTRAINT nn_cs2_users_admin NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT ck_cs2_users_admin (admin IN (0,1)),
    givenname  varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    middlename varchar2(30),
    sn         varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    mail       varchar2(50) NOT NULL
);
```

However it fails with this error:

```
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here`
```

When I connect using SQL*Plus, this is the version info:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Dec 18 16:38:27 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to specify an inline constraint, that definition is separate from the definition of the column.  You need to specify the type of the constraint if you are creating a `CHECK` constraint.  And your foreign key constraint needs to specify which column you are referencing.  So, for example, this will work

```
SQL> create table users( userid varchar2(20) primary key );

Table created.


SQL> CREATE TABLE cs2_users (
  2      empnum     varchar2(12) PRIMARY KEY,
  3      toolsId    varchar2(20) constraint nn_cs2_users_toolsId NOT NULL,
  4          CONSTRAINT fk_cs2_users_users FOREIGN KEY(toolsId) REFERENCES users(userid),
  5      admin      number(1,0) DEFAULT 0 constraint nn_cs2_users_admin NOT NULL,
  6          CONSTRAINT ck_cs2_users_admin CHECK(admin IN (0,1)),
  7      givenname  varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
  8      middlename varchar2(30),
  9      sn         varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
 10      mail       varchar2(50) NOT NULL
 11  );

Table created.
```

though it seems odd that the `toolsId` references the `userId` column from `users`.  It would seem more likely that you would want the `toolsId` column to reference the `toolsId` column from a `tools` table or that you would want to name the column something like `userId` if you want to reference the `userId` column from `users`.  But then I'd question why you have a separate `cs2_users` column rather than simply putting this information in the `users` table.

Comment: "First, there isn't a constraint type of NOT NULL so you can't create a named NOT NULL constraint". sure you can. every `not null` will create a sys generated check constraint. you can name them if you want. i.e. `create table mytab (id number constraint foo_nn1 not null);` is valid and will name the check constraint FOO_NN1 instead of SYS_Cxxxx

Comment: Right, I just got the syntax wrong.  Thanks for answering.
About the toolsId -> userId, I understand what you're saying - but basically my application is pulling together user data from two different sources, hence the "empnum" (whose values are coming from an LDAP uid field), and "toolsId" which is linking to the generic users table.  The set of applications that use this particular database are maintained by our "Tools" department, so I'm calling that field the 'toolsId'.